# How to Insert data from one table to another in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User table with id , name , e-mail etc...

i want to pass the current logged user id into another table Post , so that each post contain corresponding user id.

controller side

```
**app/controller/post_controller.rb**

    class PostController < ApplicationController
      def index
       @post=Post.new
       @posts=Post.all
      end


      def create
       @post=Post.new(params[:post])
       respond_to do |format|
       if @post.save
          format.html { redirect_to :controller=>"post" ,:action=>"index" }
         format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
         #redirect_to :controller=>"post" ,:action=>"index"
        else
         format.html { redirect_to :controller=>"home" ,:action=>"index" }
         format.json { render json: @post, status: :created, location: @post }
       end  
      end
      end
```

view part

```
**app/views/post/questions.html.erb**

<%=form_for :post do |f| %>

  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Title:<%=f.text_field :title %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Question</h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <%=f.text_area :body %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Tag:<%=f.text_field :tag %>
        </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3><%= f.submit "Post Your Question" %></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<%end%>
```

Post table contain userid , title ,body ,tag

i have stored the user id value in session when user successfully logs in........

please tell me how to add id field into Post table.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In create method instead of this `@post=Post.new(params[:post])` change it to this

```
@post=Post.new(params[:post]).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
```

and you will be good to go

Comment: i am getting an error                                          undefined method `merge' for #<Post:0x007f84df017d98>

Comment: then give a hidden field in your view like this `<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user_id %>` and change your controller to as it was before `@post=Post.new(params[:post])`